# Trying to understand differences between javafx.scene.image, awt.image, BufferedImage, RenderedImage, Raster, PlanarImage

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, tiff, jai

I am new and learning Java (more as a hobby). I am trying to write a program to display `TIFs` in `JavaFX`. I understand `TIFs` are not part of the basic `Java-8 JRE/JDK` and `JAI` needs to be used.

First, it looks like I lack the understanding between the different classes of `images`, `JavaFX Image`, `AWT Image`, `BufferedImage`, `RenderedImage`, `Raster`, `PlanarImage`, etc.

I think once I can wrap my head around those differences, I can better understand the image processing module.

I was finally able to piece together some code based on examples found. (I love the Java community because it always looks like someone has had a similar issue and someone else has resolved it).

I am able to use the `JAI` to decode a `TIFF` as a `ByteArraySeekableStream` into a `RenderedImage` and use `SwingFXUtils` to convert to a `JavaFX image`.

**Issue:** The file I am trying to process is `50-M`. I kept receiving a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` and not understanding why! (still learning).

It wasn't until I processed a `30-kB` `TIFF` that actually displayed the processed image, that I realized the `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` was due to `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`: Java heap space.

Is there a better memory managed way to process these large TIF files?

```java
static Image load(byte[] inData) throws Exception {
        Image image = null;

        SeekableStream inStream = new ByteArraySeekableStream(inData);

        ImageDecoder dec
                = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", inStream, null);

        System.out.println(dec.getInputStream());        

        RenderedImage im = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage();
        image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(PlanarImage.wrapRenderedImage(im).getAsBufferedImage(),null);

        return image;
}
```

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    String path = "charts\\DTW_sectional\\Detroit SEC 98.tif";
    //String path = "charts\\javafx-documentation.tif";

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
    FileChannel channel = in.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) channel.size());
    channel.read(buffer);

    // create JavaFX image and load into an ImageView
    Image image = load(buffer.array());
    System.out.println("Path: " + path + "\nImage: "
            + image + "\n");
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

    //Creating a Group object  
    Group root = new Group(imageView);

    //Creating a scene object 
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 500);

    //Setting title to the Stage 
    primaryStage.setTitle("Loading an image");

    //Adding scene to the stage 
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    //Displaying the contents of the stage 
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Comment: Why this `String` → `FileInputStream` → `FileChannel` → `ByteBuffer` → `byte[]` → `ByteArraySeekableStream` detour? Why not just use `new FileSeekableStream(path)`? But anyway, JAI looks much like abandonware to me. What about a simple standard API call like `BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(new File("charts\\DTW_sectional\\Detroit SEC 98.tif"));`? At least for my JDK, it reads TIFF out-of-the-box. (`BufferedImage` is a subtype of `RenderedImage`).

Comment: It seems like `.tiff` support was added in java 9 to all platforms for the `javax.imageio`: [listed for java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html), [not listed for java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html)

Comment: Yeah, and when you put the `jai_imageio.jar` into your classpath, the simple `ImageIO.read(…)` call will support TIFF on earlier versions as well.

Comment: @Holger, thanks - especially on the info on JAI!  
fabian, I want to update my Java to 11 and OpenJFX.  I just couldn't get Netbeans setup.  So, I postponed updating things until I have dedicated time....again, newbie and hobbyist....

Comment: Will going the ImageIO route save on the heap?   I am assuming I am losing the heap to the processing of the SwingFXUtils?  I thought JFX image class wants either a stream or URL of a BMP, GIF, JPEG, or PNG.  I tried using a BufferedImage  and it wouldn't display the image using image = PlanarImage.wrapRenderedImage(im).getAsBufferedImage();  But, that was using Java-8 and JavaFX-2.2.